# How to overcome can not change the admin name data and change the password?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

how to overcome the failure to change the username and password for the admin, this code succeeded in the profile of the user page, but it was not successfully used in the admin profile. Does anyone know where my code error is?

```
<?php

    include('header.php');

    $admin_user_name = '';
    $admin_password = '';
    $error_admin_user_name = '';
    $error_admin_password = '';
    $error = 0;
    $success = '';

    if (isset($_POST["button_action"])) {
        if (empty($_POST["admin_user_name"])) {
            $error_admin_user_name = 'Nama Admin harus di isi';
            $error++;
        } else {
            $admin_user_name = $_POST["admin_user_name"];
        }

        if (!empty($_POST["admin_password"])) {
            $admin_password = $_POST["admin_password"];
        }


        if ($error == 0) {
            if ($admin_password != "") {
                $data = array(
                    ':admin_user_name'           =>  $admin_user_name,
                    ':admin_password'       =>  password_hash($admin_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                    ':admin_id'             =>  $_POST["admin_id"]
                );

                $query = "
          UPDATE tbl_admin 
          SET admin_user_name = :admin_user_name, 
          admin_password = :admin_password,  
          WHERE admin_id = :admin_id
          ";
            } else {

                $data = array(
                    ':admin_user_name'           =>  $admin_user_name,
                    ':admin_id'             =>  $_POST["admin_id"]
                );

                $query = "
          UPDATE tbl_admin 
          SET admin_user_name = :admin_user_name, 
          WHERE admin_id = :admin_id
          ";
            }

            $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            if ($statement->execute($data)) {
                $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">Profil anda sudah diperbaharui</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_admin 
    WHERE admin_id = '" . $_SESSION["admin_id"] . "'
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    ?>



    <div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
        <span id="message_operation"><?php echo $success; ?></span>
        <div class="card">
            <form method="post" id="profile_form">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">Profil</div>
                        <div class="col-md-3" align="right">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Nama Admin<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="admin_user_name" id="admin_user_name" class="form-control" />
                                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_admin_user_name; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-md-4 text-right">Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="password" name="admin_password" id="admin_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Kosongkan Jika Tidak Ingin Diubah" />
                                <span class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="card-footer" align="center">

                    <input type="hidden" name="admin_id" id="admin_id" />
                    <input type="submit" name="button_action" id="button_action" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Simpan" />

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            <?php
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                ?>
                $('#admin_user_name').val("<?php echo $row['admin_user_name']; ?>");
                $('#admin_id').val("<?php echo $row['admin_id']; ?>");
            <?php
            }
            ?>


        });
    </script>
```

This code aims to change the admin name and change the admin password on the admin profile page

Comment: Your `admin_id` input doesn't appear to have a value.

Comment: where admin_id must be filled in?

Comment: `$_SESSION["admin_id"]` should be parameterized too. You should have a habit of using parameters for every value.

Comment: where I have to put the admin_id parameter ?